# How to run Python script until all data collected or certain condition met

Tags: python, api, iteration

I have a script that runs **my_func(list)**, which runs **my_request()** that hits a public API server to get data, but this query fails randomly and I get a **ResponseError**. And I have to re-run the script until all the partitions are collected (the length of **tmp_lst** is equal to the length of **df_list**).

I am curious if there is a way for me to run this script once and have the script retry N times until all the partitions are collected without having to re-run it every time I run into a **ResponseError**.

I tried to insert a while loop, but this didn't solve the issue, and I still had to manually re-run it.

```
import pandas as pd
# from pytrends.exceptions import ResponseError

def my_func(list):
    df = my_request(list) #requests api call to grab data for each element in a list
    return df # returns pandas dataframe object

df_list = [pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]]), pd.DataFrame([[5,6],[7,8]])] # there are more in my actual list

try:
if tmp_lst is not None:
    try:
        while len(tmp_lst) < len(df_list):
            for remaining_partition in range(len(tmp_lst),len(df_list)):
                tmp_lst.append(my_func(df_list[remaining_partition])) #my_func returns df
                print(f"partition {remaining_partition+1} appended")
    except ResponseError:
        print("Rate limit Exceeded. Progress: ",str(len(tmp_lst)),"/",str(len(df_list)))

except NameError:
    tmp_lst = []
    try:
        while len(tmp_lst) < len(df_list):
            for partition in range(len(df_list)):
                tmp_lst.append(my_func(df_list[partition]))
                print(f"partition {partition} appended")
    except ResponseError:
        print("Rate limit Exceeded. Progress: ",str(len(tmp_lst)),"/",str(len(df_list)))
```

Comment: In function my_request, you can put a counter and wrap your API call in try and except block. for example, the counter starts with zero for each item in your list, and if failed you add +1 to the counter, and if the counter is > N, you exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to put the try/except block inside the while loop?

Comment: haven't let me give it a try!